# Simplifying the compound extends

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

On my homepage, I would like to use other pages I have defined as sections. After my navigation, I have a portion for news and team members that run as stand alone pages on my site. It looks something like this:

```html
Header
Nav
<div class="content">
  {% include 'news.html' %}
  {% include 'officers.html' %}
</div>
Footer
```

So my news has some basic html but in order not to clone my headers and nav I have to add this line:

```html
{% if page_data.current_page == 'news' %} {% extends "base.html" %} {% endif %}
```

Is there a way to simplify this statement?

Answer (score 0):

An *alternative* way to deal with the issue is to move the body of `news.html` into a partial, for example `partials/news.html` and then `include` it in both your home page and in the news page itself:

```
{# home.html #}
Header
Nav
<div class="content">
  {% include 'partials/news.html' %}
  {% include 'officers.html' %}
</div>
Footer
```

and then in `news.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block where_news_belongs %}
    {{ super() }} {# if we need to include the contents of the block #}
    {% include 'partials/news.html %}
{% endblock where_news_belongs %}
```